# Wrong output in div element

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a web site. At a certain page , there is a div element that shows values from a PHP file.

This the PHP code that renders the info shown on the html :

```
    $output .= '

            <div class="row text-left col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 ">
            <h5><strong>Doctor '.$row['nombre_doctor'].' '.$row['apellidos_doctor'].'</strong></H5>
            <h6>'.$row['especialidad_doctor'].'<H6>
            <h6>'.$orden.' de '.get_num_doctores($row['ciudad_doctor'],$row['especialidad_doctor']).' doctores en '.$row['ciudad_doctor'].'<H6>';

        if ($puntos_doctores == 0){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-0.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          } 
        if ($puntos_doctores > 0 && $puntos_doctores <= 0.5 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-05.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          } 
        if ($puntos_doctores > 0.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 1 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-01.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          } 
        if ($puntos_doctores > 1 && $puntos_doctores <= 1.5 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-15.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          } 
        if ($puntos_doctores > 1.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 2 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-2.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          }
          if ($puntos_doctores > 2 && $puntos_doctores <= 2.5 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-25.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          }
          if ($puntos_doctores > 2.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 3 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-3.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          }
            if ($puntos_doctores > 3 && $puntos_doctores <= 3.5 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-35.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          }
           if ($puntos_doctores > 3.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 4 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-4.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          }
          if ($puntos_doctores > 4 && $puntos_doctores <= 4.5 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-45.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          }
           if ($puntos_doctores > 4.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 5 ){
       $output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-5.png" /> '
       .$num_opiniones.' opiniones <H6><br>';
          }


    $output .= ' <a class="btn btn-large btn-info" href="doctor_info.php">+ Info</a>

            </div> 

       ';
}
echo $output;
```

The output is not showing the elements as expected. 
Here you have the screenshot to understand what I mean:
[image]

The elements are ordered by the number of points, from 5 to 0.

I would like them to appear in a row with 3 columns and then another row with the remaining items. Currently the styling is off. The Cardio1 element is on a new line and offset to the right and the Cardio4 element is again on a new line.

EDIT TO SHOW COMPLETE PHP PART:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_doctores WHERE especialidad_doctor LIKE '%".$_POST["especialidad_doctor"]."%'
        AND pais_doctor LIKE '%".$_POST["pais_doctor"]."%'
        AND estado_doctor LIKE '%".$_POST["estado_doctor"]."%'
                AND ciudad_doctor LIKE '%".$_POST["ciudad_doctor"]."%' ORDER BY media_puntos DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{//05

        $output .= '<h3>Resultados por *'.$_POST['especialidad_doctor']. '* </h3>';
        $orden = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {//06
        $num_opiniones = get_num_opiniones($row['codigo_doctor']);
        $num_doctores = get_num_doctores($row['ciudad_doctor'],$row['especialidad_doctor']);
        $puntos_doctores = get_puntos_opiniones($row['codigo_doctor']);
        $puntos_doctores = (float)$puntos_doctores;
        $orden = get_orden($row['especialidad_doctor'],$row['codigo_doctor'],$row['pais_doctor'],$row['ciudad_doctor']);

if ($puntos_doctores == 0){
   $img = '0';
} else if ($puntos_doctores > 0 && $puntos_doctores <= 0.5 ){
   $img = '05';
} else if ($puntos_doctores > 0.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 1 ){          
    $img = '01';
} 
 else if ($puntos_doctores > 1 && $puntos_doctores <= 1.5 ){          
    $img = '15';
} 
else if ($puntos_doctores > 1.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 2 ){          
    $img = '2';
} 
else if ($puntos_doctores > 2 && $puntos_doctores <= 2.5 ){          
    $img = '25';
} 
else if ($puntos_doctores > 2.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 3 ){          
    $img = '3';
} 
else if ($puntos_doctores > 3 && $puntos_doctores <= 3.5 ){          
    $img = '35';
}
else if ($puntos_doctores > 3.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 4 ){          
    $img = '4';
} 
else if ($puntos_doctores > 4 && $puntos_doctores <= 4.5 ){          
    $img = '45';
} 
else if ($puntos_doctores > 4.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 5 ){          
    $img = '5';
} 


$output .= '
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5><strong>Doctor '.$row['nombre_doctor'].' '.$row['apellidos_doctor'].'</strong></H5>
            <h6>'.$row['especialidad_doctor'].'<H6>
            <h6>'.$orden.' de '.get_num_doctores($row['ciudad_doctor'],$row['especialidad_doctor']).' doctores en '.$row['ciudad_doctor'].'<H6>
            <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-' . $img . '.png" /> ' .$num_opiniones. ' opiniones <H6><br>
            <a class="btn btn-large btn-info" href="doctor_info.php">+ Info</a>
         </div> 
       </div>
   ';
    }

echo $output;




}//05
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by: The output is not showing the elements as expected.

Are you referring to the fact that Cardio1 is all the way to the right and then there is a new line and Cardio4 is on the next line?

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML (in the browser, View Source) and the CSS. That will be of more help.

Comment: @ShawnNorthrop, yes. I want to show the elements ordered from left to right according to the number of points.

Comment: Are you expecting all 5 elements to appear next to each other (there is not enough room apparently). Do you want there to be 2 rows?

Comment: @ShawnNorthrop, I am expecting three columns and the needed rows

Comment: try adding the class `col-sm-4` to the  `<h6>` elements

Comment: Also to keep it a little more DRY try the following:

`if ($puntos_doctores == 0){ $img .= '0'; }`

`else if ($puntos_doctores > 0 && $puntos_doctores <= 0.5 ){ $img = '05' }`

... continue for all points... then at the end: `$output .= '     <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-' . $img .'.png" /> '

Comment: @ShawnNorthrop, adding class col-sm-4 shows two columns and now three rows, but last element on the right side not on the left side

Comment: ^ Just a thought... not wrong what your doing but could be cleaned up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136130/discussion-between-shawn-northrop-and-mvasco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a loop that is outputting these doctors

Try the following:

```
$output .= '<div class="row">';

foreach($pointsArray as $putos_doctores){

  if ($puntos_doctores == 0){
     $img = '0';
  } else if ($puntos_doctores > 0 && $puntos_doctores <= 0.5 ){
     $img = '05';
  } else if ($puntos_doctores > 0.5 && $puntos_doctores <= 1 ){          
      $img = '01';
  } ...... finish your points else if 

  $output .= '<div class="col-md-4">
                <h5><strong>Doctor '.$row['nombre_doctor'].' '.$row['apellidos_doctor'].'</strong></H5>
                <h6>'.$row['especialidad_doctor'].'<H6>
                <h6>'.$orden.' de '.get_num_doctores($row['ciudad_doctor'],$row['especialidad_doctor']).' doctores en '.$row['ciudad_doctor'].'<H6>';
                <h6>'.$puntos_doctores.'<img class="img-responsive" width="150px" src="imagenes/estrellas/corazones-' . $img . '.png" /> ' .$num_opiniones. ' opiniones <H6><br>
                <a class="btn btn-large btn-info" href="doctor_info.php">+ Info</a>
             </div>';
}

$output .= '</div>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: I am getting now only one column

Comment: I cleaned it up even more

Comment: still needs styling tweaking though

Comment: let me check...

Comment: I'm assuming you have this code running in a loop. foreach or something?

Comment: Is there `php` code you are not showing?

Comment: iI have included all the php part involved in the issue,

Comment: You need to move the `row` outside of the loop that is printing out all of the points... I updated the answer. I'm guessing you have a loop at this point.

Comment: Now I am getting three rows and three columns. First row with first element to the left. Second row complete, and third row with last element to the right.

Comment: Hard to help any further without a full plunkr or something... try opening the developer tools / inspector and copying the html

Comment: Thank you, I will try it harder

Comment: No problem, If you are able to get a plunkr up add a comment and I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

you should apply this process to get listin

```
<? foreach(array_chunk($arrays, 3) as $array ) { ?>    
<div>    
<? foreach($array as $list) { ?>       
    <div class="class">Your content</div>
<? }; ?>    
</div> 
<? }; ?>
```